# getJSON overrides HTML background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, api

I am creating an HTML page which uses jQuery, iFrames and have simple CSS. When I run a jQuery script against a json file from openweathermap.org it overrides the HTML background color set in place, as well as any iframes. Any suggestions?

```
<style>
    body {
        background-color: #ff5000;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id = "weather"></div>
<script>
    $( "weather" ).ready(function(){ 
        $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Castlebar,ie&appid=44db6a862fba0b067b1930da0d769e98");
        document.write('hello');
        console.log('works')
    });

</script>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Comment: [DW executed after the page has finished loading will overwrite the page, or write a new page, or not work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/802943/2033671)

Comment: Please find out what does document.write - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JSON RESTful request should not be changing your background...

You need a callback function for your request so that you can process the data.

```js
$('#weather').ready(function(request) {
  $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather', {
    q     : 'Castlebar,ie',
    appid : '44db6a862fba0b067b1930da0d769e98'
  }, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var city    = data.name;
    var country = data.sys.country;
    var weather = data.weather[0].description;
    
    // Prints: "Current weather for Castlebar, IE: light rain"
    $('#weather').html('Current weather for ' + city + ', ' + country + ': ' + weather);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ff5000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="weather"></div>
```

#### JSON Response

```js
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": -9.3,
    "lat": 53.85
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 500,
      "main": "Rain",
      "description": "light rain",
      "icon": "10d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "cmc stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 278.229,
    "pressure": 1016.87,
    "humidity": 100,
    "temp_min": 278.229,
    "temp_max": 278.229,
    "sea_level": 1024.44,
    "grnd_level": 1016.87
  },
  "wind": {
    "speed": 5.27,
    "deg": 231.001
  },
  "rain": {
    "3h": 0.2
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 76
  },
  "dt": 1455729355,
  "sys": {
    "message": 0.0024,
    "country": "IE",
    "sunrise": 1455695530,
    "sunset": 1455731463
  },
  "id": 2965654,
  "name": "Castlebar",
  "cod": 200
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is to change the HTML of #weather, not rewrite the entire document. You can do this like this:

```
$('#weather').html("INSERT YOUR DESIRED CONTENT HERE");
```

So, you parse the JSON from getJSON(), extract the interesting information, and insert it into #weather with the above line of code. I have put together a JSFiddle for you with example code. I had to hardcode the json in there, because JSFiddle would not let me get the JSON from your link since it is not an HTTPS link, but simply replace `var json = *JSON*` in my Fiddle with `var json = $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Castlebar,ie&appid=44db6a862fba0b067b1930da0d769e98");` on your own page and it should work.

https://jsfiddle.net/k87yuats/

Edit: I forgot to mention that on your own page, you must use .done() feature of getJson() to make sure that the AJAX request completes before attempting to parse the JSON data: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/